# Why was my answer deleted? I think it should be undeleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655586/do-i-have-to-call-application-exitthread) question (about .NET). After a while, a user has requested additional info [by comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655586/do-i-have-to-call-application-exitthread#comment62791082_37655586). I took a look at that, read some MSDN and decided that replacing my method call with the one being part of that comment is the ultimate solution<sup>TM</sup> of the problem made me asking my question.

The title of my question was "Do I have to call Application.ExitThread()?" and the comment and my research have shown that this is not the case – I have to call `Application.DoEvents()` instead. So I wrote an answer (the one I'm asking about right now) starting with "No, I haven't.". I chose 1st person singular because I was answering my own question and I clearly explained why exactly I don't have to call that method.

I don't understand at all why my answer was deleted and I even less understand how people can comment (the answer) like that:

1. "Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information."

   - This is no "additional information" – this is an answer: "Do I have ...?" – "No, I haven't."
2. "The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question."

   - That *was* a complete answer: "Do I have ...?" – "No, I haven't. <the reason why I haven't ...>"
3. "This does not provide an answer to the question."

   - see 2.
4. "To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post."

   - (Srsly?!) Someone thinks that either

     1. I'm criticing the author of the question (myself – I answered *my own question*) or
     2. I'm requesting clarification from the author (myself – *again*)

It's a pity that (at least some) people seem not to think at all before commenting and I hope that the deletion was really my fault and you didn't delete the answer because *some moderator* took the comments at face value.

Comment: Looking at the post and your answer, I believe they were mislead by the fact that the answer starts with "No, I haven't.". It sounds like you're replying to someone, as OP of the question; thus adding information. As answerer (even if it is you, the same person), you should say "No, you shouldn't" to avoid ambiguity. (for reference, [this was the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655586/do-i-have-to-call-application-exitthread#comment62800322_37655586) converted to a comment).

Comment: Or, you could do it in the affirmative: "It's not necessary to call `Application.ExitThread()`."

Comment: @Tunaki I fixed it, but I still can't undelete :(

Comment: Looks like it has been undeleted now.

Comment: Brad the ninja mod.

Comment: Looks like an honest mistake.  It was probably flagged and it looked like a misplaced comment.

Comment: There are tons of questions about Sleep or any other for of busy wait/long operations on UI thread... Not really sure why this one deserves so much attention and implied protection by bringing it up on META... Would have downvoted both Q/A pair due to lack of research otherwise. I don't see delete answer as significant loss for the site either (especially now with better answer).

Comment: Part of it was an English-as-a-second-language thing. The converse of "Do I have to?" is "No, I don't", not "No, I haven't." The active verb is "do." "No, I haven't" sounds like you're responding to someone who said "Have you done X?" (E.g., where "have" is the active verb.) [Edit: Ah, I see Brad mentioned that in his answer.]

Comment: Generally, whenever answering directly to a specific question inside the OP post, it is a good idea to copy the sentence containing the question and add it to your answer, inside quote formatting. This makes it clear what exactly you are replying to. For example, some posts may contain several questions. Your post contained a total of 4 questions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Or after "Have I got to call X?" one could continue, "No, I haven't [got to call to X]."

Answer (score 85, accepted):

That answer was flagged by multiple people as being a response to either the other answer or one of the comments on your question. It certainly read like a comment response, because "I haven't" isn't a response in English to the question "Do I have to?".

I've rewritten the introductory sentence to your answer to make this clear (even changing it to "you haven't" still didn't read as a response to the question) and undeleted the answer.

You did the right thing by explaining this in a Meta post, because without the detail you provided above I still wouldn't have seen why this was an answer. Judging by the flags, I wasn't the only one.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114098/discussion-on-answer-by-brad-larson-what-can-i-do-if-my-answer-was-deleted-by-a).